# Where to put package in package.json? dependency or devdependency

Tags: node.js, express, npm, package.json

Just a short question.

I develop a api in node & express where i need the [package request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) for my tests and for the api logic itself. Should i put it in the normal dependencies or in the dev dependencies. Or even in both of them? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be ok, to add it to the dependencies as well as to the devDependencies. So now "npm install --dev" installs only the dependecies for the tests and "npm install" installs everything.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `dependencies` is used for packages your package depends on to run (and be used), while`devDependencies` for packages needed to develop it.

In your case, `dependencies` sounds right.

Anyway, when developing an app it is mostly for semantics - this only really matters when developing libraries and reusable components.